# ggplot2 - gridlines seem to fail for very small numbers on log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a bunch of boxplots in ggplot2 of very small numbers on a log10 scale. It seems that there's some threshold where ggplot2 stops displaying the grid properly. The plot using dat1 has the missing gridlines, while dat2 works as I would like. The difference between the two just appears to be an issue of range.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
dat1 = data.frame(
    val = c(10^(runif(90,-12,-10)), 10^(runif(10,-15,-12)),
            10^(runif(94,-12, -9)), 10^(runif(6, -14,-12))),
    d = c(rep(1,100),rep(2,100))
)

dat2 = data.frame(
    val = c(10^(runif(90,-9,-7)), 10^(runif(10,-11,-9)),
            10^(runif(94,-9,-6)), 10^(runif(6, -10,-9))),
    d = c(rep(1,100),rep(2,100))
)


p = ggplot(dat1, aes(factor(d), val))
print(p + geom_boxplot() + scale_y_log10())


p = ggplot(dat2, aes(factor(d), val))
print(p + geom_boxplot() + scale_y_log10())
```

Anyone have any advice? Is this a numerical issue with taking logs? All the values should be greater than `.Machine$double.eps`

[image: where are the gridlines!]
[image: found the gridlines!]

Comment: See https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/550

Comment: Good to know that it's a known issue. Perhaps it should be posted as an answer, just so the question can be marked as such (unless there is a possible solution out there.

Comment: Since the github issue has now been closed with a patch submitted, I'm voting to close this as too localized.